# Indexed inputs in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, razor, servicestack

I am developing a service infrastructure and admin control panel, both based on ServiceStack (admin panel is ServiceStack + Razor). In admin view I created a form that has two different indexed fields:

```
<input name="StepName[]" />
<input name="StepDescription[]" />
<input name="StepDuration[]" />

<input name="IngredientName[]" />
<input name="IngredientQuantityName[]" />
<input name="IngredientQuantityValue[]" />
```

Then I wrote admin request DTO:

```
public class StuffCreateRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string[] StepName { get; set; }
    public string[] StepDescription { get; set; }
    public int[] StepDuration { get; set; }

    public string[] IngredientName { get; set; }
    public string[] IngredientQuantityName { get; set; }
    public double[] IngredientQuantityValue { get; set; }
}
```

but all of arrayed properties are null.

The question is how to get values from theese fields?

P.S. Actually, will be better to know how to receive compound DTO (with lists, dictionaries etc.) from a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a fully working demo of how to handle the posting of collection data from a form. ServiceStack is able to convert form data into simple collections, but it can't handle complex structures, unless you use a data type such as JSON.

To get around this, I would post the data in a flatter format and then have the server expand the data into a more structured format for use in your code.

### [Full Source Code Here.](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/8705726)

#### HTML Form:

An example editor, showing multiple ingredients and steps.

[image: Recipe Editor]

#### Result:

Shows the expanded, structured data that was sent from the HTML form.
[image: Output]

---

## Method:

#### Use flat variable names in the HTML:

i.e name the variable `StepName` not `StepName[]`

```
<input type="text" name="StepName" value="1 - Prepare" />
...
<input type="text" name="StepName" value="2 - Mix" />
```

#### Set the form type:

If you are using a self hosted app, I have noticed that form data isn't populated without the explicit type set.

```
<form action="/Recipes" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

#### Setup your Request object to expect collections

```cs
[Route("/Recipes", "POST")]
public class CreateRecipeRequest : IReturn<Recipe>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string[] StepName { get; set; }
    public string[] StepDescription { get; set; }
    public int[] StepDuration { get; set; }

    public string[] IngredientName { get; set; }
    public string[] IngredientQuantityName { get; set; }
    public decimal[] IngredientQuantityValue { get; set; }
}
```

#### Convert your flattened request into a structured recipe:

```cs
public class Recipe
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Ingredient[] Ingredients { get; set; }
    public Step[] Steps { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string QuantityName { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeService : Service
{
    public Recipe Post(CreateRecipeRequest request)
    {
        // Convert the flat CreateRecipeRequest object to a structured Recipe object

        // Steps
        int numberOfSteps = request.StepName.Length;

        // Ingredients
        int numberOfIngredients = request.IngredientName.Length;

        // Check there is a description and duration for all steps
        if(request.StepDescription == null || request.StepDescription.Length != numberOfSteps || request.StepDuration == null || request.StepDuration.Length != numberOfSteps)
            throw new Exception("There must be a duration and description for all steps");

        // Create the Recipe object
        var recipe = new Recipe { Name = request.Name, Steps = new Step[numberOfSteps], Ingredients = new Ingredient[numberOfIngredients] };
        for(int s = 0; s < numberOfSteps; s++)
            recipe.Steps[s] = new Step { Name = request.StepName[s], Description = request.StepDescription[s], Duration = request.StepDuration[s] };

        // Check there is a quantity type and quantity value for all ingredients
        if(request.IngredientQuantityName == null || request.IngredientQuantityName.Length != numberOfIngredients || request.IngredientQuantityValue == null || request.IngredientQuantityValue.Length != numberOfIngredients)
            throw new Exception("The quantity must be provided for each ingredient");

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIngredients; i++)
            recipe.Ingredients[i] = new Ingredient { Name = request.IngredientName[i], QuantityName = request.IngredientQuantityName[i], Quantity = request.IngredientQuantityValue[i] };

        /*
         * Recipe can now be accessed through a logical collection:
         * 
         * recipe.Name
         * recipe.Steps[0].Name
         * recipe.Ingredients[1].Quantity
         * 
         */

        return recipe;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome post Scott!

Comment: @mythz I was feeling creative. I need to stop procrastinating ... time to work :)

Comment: For remarks, @Scott's solution also works with **ServiceStack 3.9.71**

Answer (score 2):

ServiceStack supports [posting to complex type properties](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#wiki-passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string) (or via QueryString) using the JSV format which allows you to post to collection types using a comma delimited string, e.g:

```
<form>
    <input name="StepName" value="Step1,Step2" />
    <input name="IngredientName" value="Cocoa,Vanilla" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct to assume, that if I want to post a string with commas, they need to be escaped by backslash?

Comment: @alex025 nope they'll need to be escaped with quotes, see the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#jsv-text-format-json--csv) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try cut the `[]` from html names? Like this:

```
<input name="StepName" />
<input name="StepDescription" />
<input name="StepDuration" />

<input name="IngredientName" />
<input name="IngredientQuantityName" />
<input name="IngredientQuantityValue" />
```

The ModelBinder search for properties with the same name of html `name` attribute, so don't put `[]` in the html names.

Comment: No, I want to get arrays of expected types, because there are more simillar code blocks, that add dynamically in DOM

Comment: You don't need to change your model. You need to change the html. Your model keeps the same. So your fields keep the same type, because the model determines the type of the fields not the html.

Comment: @JohnyPiazzi First, thank You for your responses! Second, myabe i explain unclear, but I want to post more than 1 fields with names StepName, StepDescription, etc. It HTML for that reason are used index suffix **[]** for field names. In my case DOM will be something like that:

`<input name="StepName" />
    <input name="StepDescription" />
    <input name="StepDuration" />
    
    <input name="IngredientName" />
    <input name="IngredientQuantityName" />
    <input name="IngredientQuantityValue" />
`

Answer (score 1):

To use a compound objects and submit your form check id out:

Create some model like this:

```
public class StuffCreateRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public StuffCreateRequestStep[] Steps { get; set; }
}

public class StuffCreateRequestStep
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
}
```

In your html you'll construct fields like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="Steps[0].Name" />
    <input name="Steps[0].Description" />
    <input name="Steps[0].Duration" />

    <input name="Steps[1].Name" />
    <input name="Steps[1].Description" />
    <input name="Steps[1].Duration" />

    <!-- add as many reps as you want (incrementing the index) -->
</form>
```

When you submit the form you will have the property `Steps` with 2 objects each with the properties filled.

**PS**: If you jump a index value the index after will be ignored. Ex:

If you submit:

```
<form>
    <input name="Steps[0].Name" />
    <input name="Steps[1].Name" />

    <input name="Steps[3].Name" />
    <input name="Steps[4].Name" />
</form>
```

Only 2 objects of Step will be created, becaus you jump the index `2`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me :( In Chrome Developer's Console I got right [data](http://pastebin.com/DPek2F9B), but [target array](http://pastebin.com/uH0XYhxd) on service is still null